# Parameterize value after @> operator using fragments

Tags: elixir, ecto

I am trying to essentially run this query in ecto but with a parameterized value:

```
select * from accounts.businesses where admins @> '{1234}';
```

This is what I have as my function definition:

```
def get_businesses_by_id(id) do
  from(b in Businesses, where: fragment("? @> '{?}'", b.admins, ^id))
  |> Repo.all()
end
```

but I get the following error:

> ** (ArgumentError) parameters must be of length 0 for query %Postgrex.Query

If I hardcode the value directly in then it works:

```
def get_businesses_by_id(id) do
  from(b in Businesses, where: fragment("? @> '{1234}'", b.admins))
  |> Repo.all()
end
```

Any insight into how I can effectively parameterize the ID value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use "placeholder" inside string, but you do not need string, you need array, so you can do:

```
fragment("? @> ?", b.admins, ^[id])
```

But as [GIN index also supports `=` operator on arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/interactive/gin-builtin-opclasses.html) it should also work with `ANY` so you could just write:

```
where: ^id in b.admins
```

Comment: Thanks, the 1st solution with the fragment clause worked! However I tested the 2nd solution using the ANY command and it did not invoke the GIN index when I disabled seq_scan for the database.

Answer (score 0):

Unless using [`@>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-array.html) operator is absolutely necessary, using [`ANY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.28.16) should work:

```
def get_businesses_by_id(id) do
  from(b in Businesses, where: fragment("? = ANY(?)", ^id, b.admins))
  |> Repo.all()
end
```

Comment: I wanted to use the @> operator because I have a GIN index for the column. From what I've understand, using @> guarantees it will use the index when appropriate

Comment: @john do not "quess", measure.